# how to properly size an image view within a grid view on java side; android?

Tags: android, gridview, sizing

this is my code to put some image doodads in my GridView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView v;
        if(convertView == null) {
            v = new ImageView(c);
            v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(90,90));
            v.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            v.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        } else {
            v = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        v.setImageDrawable(c.getResources().getDrawable(ops[position]));
        return v;
    }
```

but for smaller machines the layoutParams are too big, does anyone know how i can do like a (90dp, 90dp) for the width and height on the java side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a dimension in XML :

```
<dimen name="image_size">90dp</dimen>
```

Then get it from your code :

```
int size = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_size);
v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size));
```

You can also set different dimensions depending on the screen sizes, by creating different `values` folders.

For example, put a large dimension in a folder named `values-w600dp` (which will be used if the width of the screen is greater or equal to 600dp) and a smaller one in the simple `values` folder (you will have two dimens.xml files).

You will find more details [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers).

Comment: and i declare this in strings.xml?

Comment: No, `dimens.xml` (although you can put it in strings.xml, but it's better to create a separate file for dimensions).

Comment: it seems like v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size, size)); doesnt take floats, would it still work if i cast it an int?

Comment: hmm... well it worked, and the images fit on the smaller machines, but now its too small on the bigger machines..